# What is my Grandpa's collar insignia?

Tags: world-war-two, identification, uniform

This is a photograph of my grandpa, Douglas Howard. At his retirement, I believe he was a Major in the Devon and Dorset, but my info is vague. This was a photo he gave to his future wife, and my grandma, early in his military career. The shoulder patch looks like the 43rd Wessex Infantry Division, but I cannot find any collar badges, online, that seem to match the rather indistinct images. Not helped by no cap! Any help gratefully received.

[image: Image of Douglas Howard in uniform]

Comment: Please provide his full name, date of birth, and anything you have about when he joined the army, and when he was commissioned. I should be able to find him in the PDFs of the Army List, if we can narrow the date down a bit, and that will give us his regiment. He's a second lieutenant in this picture, of course, so if you know its date, that would help.